# Codeigniter xss vulnerabilities and other problems with security

Tags: security, codeigniter, xss

When i scanned my site with "Acunetix Web Vulnerability Scanner" i was very surprised. Programm show a lot of xss vulnerabilities on page when i use get parameters with xss filtration. 
For example:

```
URL encoded GET input state was set to " onmouseover=prompt(967567) bad="
The input is reflected inside a tag parameter between double quotes.
```

I think its because i don`t show 404 error when result is empty (it should be). I show message like "the request is empty"

My controller:

```
$this->pagination->initialize($config); 
    $this->load->model('aircraft_model');

    $data['type'] = $this->input->get('type', TRUE);
    $data['year'] = $this->input->get('year', TRUE);
    $data['state'] = $this->input->get('state', TRUE);
        $type_param = array (
        'type'    => $this->input->get('type', TRUE),
        );

        $parameters = array(
        'year'    => $this->input->get('year', TRUE),
        'state_id'   => $this->input->get('state', TRUE),
        );
        foreach ($parameters as $key=>$val)
                {
                    if(!$parameters[$key])
                    {
                        unset($parameters[$key]);
                    }
                }

    $data['aircraft'] = $this->aircraft_model->get_aircraft($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3, 1),$parameters, $type_param);
    $data['title'] = 'Самолеты | ';
    $data['error'] = '';
    if (empty($data['aircraft']))
    {
       $data['error'] = '<br /><div class="alert alert-info"><b>По таким критериям не найдено ниодного самолета</b></div>';
    }

    $name = 'aircraft';
    $this->template->index_view($data, $name);
```

even when i turn on global xss filtering program find xss vulnerabilities.
Maybe Message for possible xss is false?

Also i have one SQL injection.

```
Attack details:
Path Fragment input / was set to \
Error message found: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax
```

SQL error:

```
Error Number: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-10, 10' at line 3
SELECT * FROM (`db_cyclopedia`) LIMIT -10, 10
```

Controller:

```
$this->load->model('cyclopedia_model');
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

    [pagination config]

    $config['suffix'] = '/?'.http_build_query(array('type' => $this->input->get('type', TRUE)), '', "&");

    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'cyclopedia/page/';
    $count_all = $this->cyclopedia_model->count_all($this->input->get('type', TRUE));
    if (!empty($count_all)){
    $config['total_rows'] = $count_all;    
    }
    else
    {
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('cyclopedia');
    }
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $config['first_url'] = base_url().'cyclopedia/page/1'.'/?'.http_build_query(array('type' => $this->input->get('type', TRUE)), '', "&");

    $this->pagination->initialize($config); 

        $parameters = array(
        'cyclopedia_cat_id' => $this->input->get('type', TRUE),
        );
        foreach ($parameters as $key=>$val)
                {
                    if(!$parameters[$key])
                    {
                        unset($parameters[$key]);
                    }
                }
    $data['type'] = $this->input->get('type', TRUE);   
    $data['cyclopedia'] = $this->cyclopedia_model->get_cyclopedia($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3, 1),$parameters);
    $data['title'] = 'Энциклопедия | ';
    if (empty($data['cyclopedia']))
    {
        show_404();
    }

    $name = 'cyclopedia';
    $this->template->index_view($data, $name);
```

And one some problems with HTTP Parameter Pollution (get parameters).

```
Attack details
URL encoded GET input state was set to &n954725=v953060
Parameter precedence: last occurrence
Affected link: /aircraft/grid/?type=&year=&state=&n954725=v953060
Affected parameter: type=
```

Sorry for a lot of code, but its my first experience with codeigniter / framework and safety first.

**UPDATE**:
When site url like this site.com/1 codeigniter show:

```
An Error Was Encountered
Unable to load your default controller. Please make sure the controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid.
```

how to make a show 404 instead of this message?

Comment: In general CI security is weak. With regard to XSS filtering, they take a somewhat questionable approach. XSS is an output problem, they treat it like an input problem. What you could (should) do is check each input parameter with an regex or something like that. Forget the 'global XSS check', it doesn't work that way. Whitelist every acceptable value of pattern. Also make sure you escape everything you inject into SQL or some other language.

Comment: @patrick-savalle is it possible to do what you wrote means CodeIgniter? (if yes, can you show me how on my example)
I do not know how to test with regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This takes input from the user:

```
$config['first_url'] = base_url().'cyclopedia/page/1'.'/?'.http_build_query(array('type' => $this->input->get('type', TRUE)), '', "&");
```

Then this line in the Pagination.php library spits it into the output page without proper HTML-escaping:

```
$output .= $this->first_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$first_url.'">'.$this->first_link.'</a>'.$this->first_tag_close;
```

Although automated scanning tools do generate a lot of false positives in general, this one is a genuine HTML-injection vulnerability leading to a real risk of cross-site scripting attacks.

To fix, wrap all output being injected into HTML context (eg `$first_url`) with `htmlspecialchars()`. Unfortunately as this is library code you would have to start your own fork of Pagination. Might be better to use some other library.

Don't rely on `xss_clean` as it can't reliably protect you. It is attempting to deal with output problems at the input layer, which is never going to work right - it'll miss attacks as well as mangling perfectly valid input. The whole idea betrays a basic, rookie misunderstanding of what the XSS problem actually is.

There are more places in Pagination that need the same fix, but I don't want to spend any more time reading CodeIgniter's painfully poor-quality code than I have to.

I do not understand how CodeIgniter has attained this degree of popularity.